# iterating a two dimentional dict to remove a dict

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional associative array (dictionary). I'd like to iterate over the first dimension using a for loop, and extract the second dimension's dictionary at each iteration.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
doubleDict = dict()
doubleDict['one'] = dict()
doubleDict['one']['type'] = 'animal'
doubleDict['one']['name'] = 'joe'
doubleDict['one']['species'] = 'monkey'
doubleDict['two'] = dict()
doubleDict['two']['type'] = 'plant'
doubleDict['two']['name'] = 'moe'
doubleDict['two']['species'] = 'oak'

for thing in doubleDict:
        print thing
        print thing['type']
        print thing['name']
        print thing['species']
```

My desired output:

```
{'type': 'plant', 'name': 'moe', 'species': 'oak'}
plant
moe
oak
```

My actual output:

```
two
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print thing['type']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I missing?

PS I'm aware I can do a `for k,v in doubleDict`, but I'm *really* trying to avoid having to do a long `if k == 'type': ... elif k == 'name': ...` statement. I'm looking to be able to call `thing['type']` directly.

Comment: I think what you're missing is that `for thing in doubleDict` is iterating over the keys of that dict.

Comment: If you want a two-dimensional dictionary where the keys to the first level are just things like 'one', 'two', etc. why not just use a list of dictionaries? Lists also have O(1) random access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For-loops in `dict`s iterates over the keys and not over the values.

To iterate over the values do:

```
for thing in doubleDict.itervalues():
        print thing
        print thing['type']
        print thing['name']
        print thing['species']
```

I used your exact same code, but added the `.itervalues()` at the end which means: "I want to iterate over the values".

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate through a dictionary, you iterate through it's keys and not its values. To get nested values, you have to do:

```
for thing in doubleDict:
    print doubleDict[thing]
    print doubleDict[thing]['type']
    print doubleDict[thing]['name']
    print doubleDict[thing]['species']
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic way to get to the nested results:

```
for thing in doubleDict.values():
  print(thing)
  for vals in thing.values():
    print(vals)
```

or

```
for thing in doubleDict.values():
  print(thing)
  print('\n'.join(thing.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Haidro's answer but make it more generic with a double loop:

```
for key1 in doubleDict:
    print(doubleDict[key1])
    for key2 in doubleDict[key1]:
        print(doubleDict[key1][key2])


{'type': 'plant', 'name': 'moe', 'species': 'oak'}
plant
moe
oak
{'type': 'animal', 'name': 'joe', 'species': 'monkey'}
animal
joe
monkey
```

Answer (score 0):

these all work... but looking at your code, why not use a named tuple instead?

from collections import namedtuple

LivingThing = namedtuple('LivingThing', 'type name species')

doubledict['one'] = LivingThing(type='animal', name='joe', species='monkey')

doubledict['one'].name
doubledict['one']._asdict['name']